# Block user from revoking CONTROL to schema when granted CONTROL on a schema

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I recently ran into an interesting conundrum. We grant CONTROL on schemas to developers to lock them down to just changes in the schema. Recently we started using database projects. One of the developers made some changes to a proc and then used the schema compare tool to push the changes to the development sql server. The database project did not contain the roles that had been granted CONTROL so the compare generated REVOKE CONTROL on the schemas. So his compare script failed as he immediately revoked himself when applying the compare changes.

I know the easy fix is to add the roles and grants to the schema in the database project so this will not happen again, but is there a way to block the developer from revoking their control of the schema? I've tried seeing if I could do it with permissions or a server ddl trigger, but nothing seems to pop out.

For now I have done the easy fix, but I would like to know how to block them from accidentally doing this again if possible.